# Property \"IsAnchor\" does not have corresponding setter

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, category-attribute

I am trying to set the IsAnchor attribute for individual categories via the api however, I keep running into this error.

```
{"message":"Property \"IsAnchor\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Catalog\\Api\\Data\\CategoryInterface\".","trace":"#0...
```

I am using the catalogCategoryRepositoryV1
/V1/categories/{id} operation.

When I do a get, I can see that the property does exist. 
[image]

Has anyone run into this issue before?

I have not found a solution via google.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to create or update a category's anchor status via RESTApi the solution is to send the attribute as a custom attribute.

Here are a few other attributes that you would also need to send as custom attributes.
[image]